# Don't test certain assemblies in parallel

Tags: c#, nunit, nunit-console

I am runing some unit tests on multiple assemblies using nunit3-console, like this:

```
nunit3-console.exe A.dll B.dll C.dll D.dll
```

The console runner is testing all these assemblies in parallel by default.

I would like to run A.dll and B.dll in parallel, but I need C.dll and D.dll to not run in parallel. So running in parallel is ok, as long as C.dll and D.dll are not running at the same time.

How can I achieve this? I have tried using `[assembly: NonParallelizable]` on both C.dll and D.dll, however it looks like they are still running in parallel.

Comment: Have you tried adding `--process=Single` as an option? That should make the assemblies not run in parallel but then all of them will run single threaded, so might not be exactly what you are looking for

Comment: This would work, but it would disable all parallelism. I was looking for a way to keep parallelism in some assemblies but not others.